# How would you except this undefined method

Tags: javascript, exception

I would like to check if the element exists and one of the methods is not blank?

Please have a look at the following code:

```
                 
var description;           
var desc = forecasts[i].getElementsByTagName('desc')[0]
if (desc != null || desc.textContent == "") {
    description = desc.textContent
}
```

So basically if the element is not defined it gives me an error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of undefined`

Well, I can use nested `ifs`, but I think there should be a niftier solution for this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your condition is wrong:

```
desc != null || desc.textContent == ""
```

Because `undefined != null` evaluates to `false`, the condition will then attempt to access `desc.textContent`.

It seems that you want to copy the contents if it exists and is not empty; this can be done with the following condition:

```
var description,
desc = forecasts[i].getElementsByTagName('desc')[0];

if (desc && desc.textContent.length) {
    description = desc.textContent;
}
```

Comment: Actually undefined == null is true. Try it... Only undefined === null is wrong. The problem was the or operator you "fixed" in your answer

Comment: @MofX Thanks for spotting that, I meant to say it evaluates to `false`, but I forgot to put that in my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var description;           
var desc = forecasts[i].getElementsByTagName('desc')[0]
if (desc && desc.textContent) {
    description = desc.textContent
}
```

`var string = ""; if (string)` Evaluates to false in JavaScript so you can simply remove the  equality check and make sure that `desc.textContent` doesn't evaluate to false.

You should also remove the OR operator as you are saying if `desc` exists but `desc.textContent` doesn't go ahead and get `desc.textContent`. Replace your OR statement with an AND operator `if (desc && desc.textContent)`.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/pFBpc/5/ - Note there are 3 if statements but only one evaluates to true.

Comment: `desc.textContent` will actually result in an error because `desc` is not defined in this case.

Comment: @Jack I see was just testing this and I've updated my answer.

Comment: The code is now correct, but the rest of the answer doesn't seem to relate to it very well.

Comment: @Jack I don't see why you think that, it explains the changes I made to his original code.